# Find the value of $f'(2)$ where $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{n}\arctan(\frac{x}{n(n+1)+x^2})$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, derivatives

Find the value of $f'(2)$ where $$f(x)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n(n+1)+x^2}\right)$$
I could not find $f(x)$ here. I had a feeling that Riemann integral should be used to find the $f(x)$ but i cannot find after some efforts. Please help me.

Comment: Can you please fix the contradictory usage of $n$ both as a free and a bound variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\arctan\left(\frac{x}{n(n+1)+x^2}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{n+1}{x}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{n}{x}\right)\\\implies f(x)=\arctan(x)$$